Why do binomial expansion represent ways of picking things?
I was looking at a question which asked for

The number of ways of to 8 letters from a group of 24 letters out of which 8 are N's, 8 are M's and the rest are unique.

The answer said that it is the coefficient of $x^8$ in $$(1+x+x^2+x^3....x^8)(1+x+x^2+x^3.....x^8)(1+x)^8$$
My question how this question of permutation and combination is somehow related to the coefficient of the binomial expansion in this particular equation?

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

A selection is a Bernoulli trial on each eligible object. Either it's picked or it's not. Essentially outcomes of Bernoulli trials group themselves acvording to the binomial distribution

Remembering that $(1 + x)^n = (1 + x)(1 + x)\ldots(1 + x)$, where there are $n$ copies of $(1+x)$ on the right-hand side, what happens when you multiply everything out?
You have a bunch of $1$ and $x$ terms multiplied together, which will form terms of $x^k$ when you multiply $k$ lots of $x$ with $(n-k)$ lots of $1$.
So then how many of those $x^k$ terms will you get? You will get as many terms as there are ways to select $k$ lots of $x$ and $(n - k)$ lots of $1$, which means out of the $n$ $(1 + x)$ terms, you need to choose $k$ of them to contribute their $x$.
How many ways can that happen? As many ways as there are to choose $k$ terms out of a possible set of $n$, i.e. $^n C_k$.
